# how to insert the variables from the loop into an associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following loop:

```
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

           echo "Key:" . $key . " Value: ". $value .   "<br />";         

           }
```

which produce the following result:

Key:1 Value: my value 
Key:8 Value: my some other value
Key:9 Value: another value

What I am trying to do is to create an array that would look like this:

```
$editWhat = array(
                'field1'            => $key1,
                'field2'            => $key2,
                'field3'            => $key3,
                'field4'        => $value1,
                'field5'        => $value2,
                'field6'        => $value3
            );
```

Comma should be stripped in the last value pair line in the array, which cause me additional problems.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: Are you trying to create an array with those key, value pairs, or are you simply trying to print them to look like an associative array?

Comment: please clearify your question

Comment: I am trying to create an array

Comment: Okay, then the answers below are correct. I just wasn't sure, because the code you posted is all about printing out the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$editWhat = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $editWhat['field'.(count($editWhat)+1)] = $key;
foreach($_POST as $value)
    $editWhat['field'.(count($editWhat)+1)] = $value;
```

will do exactly what you described. If you don't need the keys of the array you can do:

```
$editWhat = array_merge(array_keys($_POST), array_values($_POST));
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed. I will accept your answer in 40 seconds :-)

Comment: To the one how downvoted me: can you explain why? Is there a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand but try this to get your desired array:

```
$editWhat = array();
$count = count($_POST);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $editWhat['field'.($key+1)] = $key;
    $editWhat['field'.($key+$count+1)] = $value;
}
```

Comment: add a second loop storing the values and you get my +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the array values to the corresponding key within the loop:

```
$editWhat = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $editWhat[$key] = $value;  

}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Hi Louis... I get $editWhat = array(
                    'key1'            => $value1,
                    'key2'            => $value2,
                  
                );   which is not I want...take a look on my question

Answer (score 0):

```
$editWhat=array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

           $editWhat[$key] = $value;         

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_keys()` and `array_values()` functions to loop through keys and values of array and using two separate loops construct a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $keys[]=$key;
    $values[]=$value;
}
foreach($keys as $editKey){
    $editWhat[]=$editKey;
}
foreach($values as $editValue){
    $editWhat[]=$editVlaue;
}
```

Comment: why do you store the keys and values before you loop over them? You could use `array_values()` and `array_keys()` or simply loop over the `$_POST` and directly insert into `$editWhat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = array();
$n = 1;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $array["field".$n] = $key; 
      $n++;
 }

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
      $array["field".$n] = $value; 
      $n++; 
}

print_r($array);
```